# Piecewise Function Alignment

Tags: formatting, align

The third row of the piecewise function does dot align with the first two rows

```
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
2x   & -2<x \\
2 & -2\le x\le  1 \\
3x^2 & 1<x\\
\end{cases}
\]
```

How can I resolve this issue

Comment: Is this the output you would like to achieve?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsVab.png

Comment: yes. it definetly is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of `\phantom`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
2x   & -2<x \\
2 & -2\le x\le  1 \\
3x^2 & \phantom{-}1<x\\
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```